# Switch on the fly between two sources in gstreamer

Tags: c, gstreamer

I'm currently facing a problem that I'm not able to resovle yet, but I hope I can do it with your help.

I currently developp an application with gstreamer to playback different kind of files : video and photo (avi and jpg respectively). The user has to have the possibility to switch between those different files. I have achieved this but by creating a new pipeline if the file format is different. There, screen randomly blinks between two files loading.

Now, I've played with valve just for jpg files and it works like a charm. But, I'm stuck at the step to implement video files, I don't know how to swith between two video files : the code below doesn't work for video files, it freezes:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc name=photosrc ! jpegdec ! valve name=playvalve drop=false ! imxg2dvideosink
```

Then further in my code, I drop the valve, set differents elements to ready state, change location of filesrc and return to playing state.

I take a look a input-selector but it appears that non-read file still playing when one switches to the other (cf doc). Is it possible to set an input as ready to avoid this behavior ?

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Why the [tag:c] tag?

Comment: Cause I work with c language in this project.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/RidgeRun/gst-interpipe plugin.

You can create 2 different source *mini* pipelines ending with interpipesink, and in runtime change which will connect to interpipesrc. Make sure to have the same format on both ends. Or use renegotiation capability, however, I have not tried it yet.

Check [wiki](http://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php?title=GstInterpipe_-_Dynamic_Switching) for dynamic switching details:

```
/* Create pipelines */
GstElement *pipe1 = gst_parse_launch ("videotestsrc ! interpipesink name=camera1", NULL);
GstElement *pipe2 = gst_parse_launch ("videotestsrc ! interpipesink name=camera2", NULL);
GstElement *pipe3 = gst_parse_launch ("interpipesrc name=src listen-to=camera1 ! fakesink", NULL);

/* Grab a reference to the interpipesrc */
GstElement *src = gst_bin_get_by_name(pipe3, "src");

/* Perform the switch */
g_object_set (src, "listen-to", "camera2", NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you @JakubPiskorz for this idea. I have to find a way to compile it for imx6 target and then test it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a little bit tricky for me to compile this plugin for imx6 target...
Is it possible to change pipeline like this :

```
 - ----.      .----------.      .---- -       .---- -
 filesrc     | avidemux |      | vpudec      | imxg2dsink
     src -> sink       src -> sink    src -> sink
- ----'      '----------'      '---- -       '---- -
```

to

```
 - ----.      .----------.      .---- -
  filesrc     | jpedec   |      | imxg2dsink
      src -> sink       src -> sink   
 - ----'      '----------'      '---- -
```

Without set all pipeline to null ?

I've tried to create a new pipeline at each time I change the location of filesrc, it works but sometimes the framebuffer blinks ....
When I change location of filesrc in case of jpeg file, it works. In case I change location of avi file, pipeline doesn't restart correctly :

```
avidemux gstavidemux.c:5678:gst_avi_demux_loop:<demux> error: Internal data stream error.
avidemux gstavidemux.c:5678:gst_avi_demux_loop:<demux> error: streaming stopped, reason not-linked
```

Thank you.